# Javascript to add links to mobile menu when screen size is smaller. No longer works.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I had built a site with a mobile navigation when the browser width is less than 1024px. I used this javascript (with jQuery) to add some links to close the menu. The Site now is not loading these links, and is open on page load, instead of closed. Am i missing some obvious reason why this isn't working?

agirlwithacupcake.com is the live site using wordpress.

```
var eventFired = 0;

if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    $('#navigation').hide();
    $('.menu-main-menu-minus-store-container ul').before('<a href="#" class="menutoggle arrow-left">&#x25BC;</a>');
    $('.menu-main-menu-minus-store-container ul').before('<a href="#" class="menutoggle arrow-right">&#x25BC;</a>');

}
else {
    $('#navigation').show();
    eventFired = 1;
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if (!eventFired) {
        if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
            $('#navigation').hide();
            $('.menu-main-menu-minus-store-container ul').before('<a href="#" class="menutoggle arrow-left">&#x25BC;</a>');
            $('.menu-main-menu-minus-store-container ul').before('<a href="#" class="menutoggle arrow-right">&#x25BC;</a>');
        } else {
                $('#navigation').show();
        }
    }
});
```

I apologize if my question is worded strange or I'm doing something wrong in the post. This is my first interaction here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

I checked your site and it looks like   "eventfired"    is not defined (even though you have it defined above in your post).

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
if (!eventFired) {
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
        $('#navigation').hide();
        $('.menu-main-menu-minus-store-container ul').before('<a href="#" class="menutoggle arrow-left">&#x25BC;</a>');
        $('.menu-main-menu-minus-store-container ul').before('<a href="#" class="menutoggle arrow-right">&#x25BC;</a>');
    } else {
            $('#navigation').show();
    }
}});
```

get rid of

```
if(!ebentFired) {}
```

or make sure to add

```
var eventFired = 0;
```

to http://agirlwithacupcake.com/wp-content/themes/agirlwithacupcake/lib/js/scripts.js

I would recommend to always check firebug it's a big help in troubleshooting. 
http://getfirebug.com/